# Git: is it possible to push from one remote to another

Tags: git, git-remote

So my old remote is on Bitbucket, and i would like to transfer everything to Visualstudio Cloud.

I already have a local repo, but i since the internet is way too slow here, is it possible to tell remote 1 to push to remote 2 instead of pushing from local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't ask Bitbucket to Visualstudio cloud.

But you can ask Visualstudio Cloud to *pull from Bitbucket*, or more precisely, to clone your Bitbucket repo.

[See the instructions in the Team Services doc](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/import-git-repository)